# Can't Run Rails Server Gem Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying Rails framework on windows 7 so i've installed it and created new project, but when I try to run:

```
$rails server
```

I get back an error:

"could not find `gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32'"`. so i installed this gem: `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]` and it worked.

Now i get this error:

> Could not find gem rails (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32 in any of the gem
>   sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. Run
>   bundle install to install missing gems.

help please.

Comment: have your run `bundle install` ?

Comment: yes and it didn't solve the prob

Comment: Which versions do you get with `rails -v` and `ruby -v` ?

Comment: rails -v: 4.2.5.1  ruby -v: 2.1.5

Comment: What do you get when you run `bundle update` & `bundle install`? Does it report any errors or does it report that the gem installed normally. Can you post your Gemfile.lock?